# How to keep chatbox scroll position when using jQuery Interval load?

Tags: jquery, load, setinterval, scrolltop

I have a little problem with my chatbox, when i try to read content, I'm getting back at very last line every 10sec and lose the line you were reading..

My chatbox is using two files,

**file #1: chat index**
Using jQuery load & setInterval function to reload the file that contain chat logs created by PHP.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#chatbox_content").load("chatbox_logs.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#chatbox_content").load("chatbox_logs.php");
   }, 10000); // refresh each 10sec
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

**file #2: chat logs maker**
Simply using scrollTop function onload, to keep the scroll at the very bottom on the designated div.

-

I want to know, if its possible to detect the scroll position of file #2 on file #1 before next Interval reload,
so i can use on file #1 :

```
$("#chatbox_content").load("chatbox_logs.php?scroll=scrollTop_var");
```

file #2 will just use PHP _GET[] to set the good scroll position onload.